# If I subclass from EKReminder will I be able to save my custom class to the eventstore on iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I would like to develop a custom Reminders application. The properties and methods the EKReminder has by default are not enough. If I subclass it and then add all the extra properties and stuff I need will I be able to save it to the iCloud reminders/calendar event store?

Will the "normal" Reminders app be able to "see" my saved custom reminders and manipulate part of data it can see on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EKReminder(subclass of EKCalendarItem : EKObject : NSObject just like EKEvent) is not meant to be subclassed. Event Kit objects are used to represent database records. Creating a subclass of EKReminder will not magically insert new fields in the Event Kit database, nor will casting a EKReminder to something else magically change that object' class.

The only way to store extra fields into the database is to have a direct access to that database, which Apple reserves for themselves.

As you cannot add new fields to the Event Kit database, you can either use the existing fields (for example, add the event ID in the notes of the event) or extend it with a second database managed by your application (in which case you can't use calDAV to store your objects).

Found the answer here and modified it to fit my question.
[Properly subclassing the EKEvent Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401309/properly-subclassing-the-ekevent-class?rq=1)